# How can I save an array using Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, parse-platform

I am struggling to use Parse to save an array of data - or at least I am finding I can't verify that my data is being saved.

I have a PFObject (journey) and I want to update it with my location (a string in the format: @"{lat, long}").

Eventually though I want to update and save my location every 10-30 seconds meaning I don't want to create a new object each time rather I want to add an array to the object and then update the array each time I have a new location.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)startJourneyButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    PFObject * journey = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Journey"];
    journey[@"company"] = _companyNameTextField.text;
    journey[@"destination"] = _destinationTextField.text;

    [journey saveInBackground];

    NSData * faceImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([_faceButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
    PFFile * faceImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"faceImage.png" data:faceImageData];

    [faceImageFile saveInBackground];

    NSData * carImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([_carButton2 imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
    PFFile * carImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"carImage.png" data:carImageData];

    [carImageFile saveInBackground];

    journey[@"faceImage"] = faceImageFile;
    journey[@"carImage"] = carImageFile;

    [journey saveInBackground];

    NSMutableArray * locationArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [locationArray addObject:[self getCurrentLocationString]];

    journey[@"location"] = locationArray;

    [journey saveInBackground];
}
```

The strings are saving fine and so are the images but the dataBase doesn't seem to be getting uploaded with the array.

Here is a screenshot of my database:

[image: Parse DataBase]

I am expecting to see a "location" heading but obviously it isn't appearing.

Reading up on other forums it says that I have to have an object in JSON format for this to work but as I am only storing Strings and I am not receiving and JSON errors I don't think this is the issue.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is saving your array, you should just manually in your database add column with name **"location"** (do not forget to set it as `array` type) to see the values.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly, I added a column to the table and the data that I was saving was immediately in that array column.

Comment: Is there  a way to input the predefined array data in Parse.com?

Comment: The way to input the predefined array data in the Parse "Core" UI - assuming that the column is of type "Array" - is the same as it would be represented in JSON, enclosed in square brackets [] and each value within double quotes. For example:

["value1","value2","value3"]